# PHP strpos() function comparision of string conflicts in numbers

Tags: php, strpos

I am using strpos() function to find the string in an array key members.

```
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    // for all types of questions of chapter 1 only
    $count = 0;
    if(strpos($k, 'chap1') !== false){
        $count++;
    }
}
```

I know that it works only until the keys are (chap1e1, chap1m1, chap1h1) but when it comes to (chap10e1, chap10m1, chap10h1), my logic won't be working on those.

Isn't there any way, so that, I can distinguish the comparison between (chap1 & chap10)?

Or, Is there any alternative way of doing this? Please give me some ideas on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `preg_match` would do just that:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if (preg_match('/\bchap1[^\d]{0,1}/', $k)) ++$count;
}
```

How the pattern works:

- `\b`: a word-boundary. matches `chap1`, but not `schap`, it can't be part of a bigger string
- `chap1`: matches a literal string (because it's preceded by `\b`, this literal can't be preceded by a char, but it can be the beginning of a string, for example
- `[^\d]{0,1}`: Matches anything *except* numbers zero or one times. so `chap10` is not a match, but `chap1e` is

To deal with all of these *"chapters"* at once, try this:

```
$count = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if (preg_match('/\bchap(\d+)(.*)/', $k, $match))
    {
        $match[2] = $match[2] ? $match[2] : 'empty';//default value
        if (!isset($count[$match[1]])) $count[$match[1]] = array();
        $count[$match[1]][] = $match[2];
    }
}
```

Now this pattern is a bit more complex, but not much

- `\bchap`: same as before, wourd boundary + literal
- `(\d+)`: Match *AND GROUP* all numbers (one or more, no numbers aren't accepted). We use this group as key later on (`$match[1]`)
- `(.*)`: match *and group* the rest of the string. If there's nothing there, that's OK. If you don't want to match keys like `chap1`, and require something *after* the digits, replace the `*` asterisk with a plus sign

Now, I've turned the `$count` variable into an array, that will look like this:

```
array('1' => array('e1', 'a3'),
      '10'=> array('s3')
);
```

When `$_POST` looks something like this:

```
array(
    chap1e1 => ?,
    chap1a3 => ?,
    chap10s3=> ?
)
```

What you do with the values is up to you. One thing you could do is to group the key-value pairs per *"chapter"*

```
$count = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if (preg_match('/\bchap(\d+)/', $k, $match))
    {
        if (!isset($count[$match[1]])) $count[$match[1]] = array();
        $count[$match[1]][$k] = $v;//$match[1] == chap -> array with full post key->value pairs
    }
}
```

Note that, if this is a viable solution for you, it's not a bad idea to simplify the expression (because regex's are best kept simple), and just omit the `(.*)` at the end.
With the code above, to get the count of any *"chap\d"* param, simply use:

```
echo 'count 1: ', isset($count[1]) ? count($count[1]) : 0, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, my mind never thought of preg_match() function, i used it with email validation. I just remembered! Thank you Elias Sir.

Comment: @ManishShrestha: Get `preg_match` out of that bit of your mind that deals with email validation, and fill the vacant space with `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` it's faster, and almost certainly more complete than any regex you will write

Comment: So, I see that, I am acknowledged with something new today. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

you may need tweaking the reg ex code,anyway this will give a start

```
if (preg_match("/chap[0-9]{1,3}/i", $v, $match)) {
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: your approach matches `chap0`, as well as `chap999`, the op wants to distinguish between `chap1` and `chap10`, this code doesn't do that. At all

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$rest = substr($k, 0, 5);
```

and then compare your string like **($rest !== 'chap1')**

I hope this works.

Comment: `$k = 'chap10'; echo substr($k, 0, 5);` still yields `chap1`, which is exactly what the OP _doesn't_ want

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code on [Execute PHP Online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php)

```
<?php
    $_POST['chap1e1'] = 'test1';
    $_POST['chap10e1'] = 'test2';
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    // for all types of questions of chapter 1 only
    $count = 0;
    var_dump($k);
    var_dump(strpos($k, 'chap1'));
    var_dump(strpos($k, 'chap1') !== false);
}
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    // for all types of questions of chapter 1 only
    //$count = 0;
    var_dump($count);
    if(strpos($k, 'chap1') !== false){
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
?>
```

And the get the below output
string(7) "chap1e1" int(0) bool(true) string(8) "chap10e1" int(0) bool(true) int(0) int(1) 2

Indicating the strpos is able to locate "chap1" in "chap10e1"
but the $count total is wrong because your code always reset $count to 0 inside the foreach loop